# Laptop stand fans direction?

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling

I have just purchased a portable laptop stand with some cooling fans that come attached but something seems the wrong way around.

The fans air directtion pulls air through the laptop stand and down onto my legs. Two things seem wrong

1 - My legs get cold. Obviously i cannot sit here freezing my legs as two fans blow down on them.

2 - The fan system in the laptop has one vent for airflow in, and one for out. The inward flow is positioned underneath the machine in a long line under the function keys. Surely then if these fans are meant to suck air in, the fans under the laptop stand are going to add strain to the laptop fans?

Should the fans not blow air upward in favour of the laptops inward fan system. This would not chill my legs as much and also would compliment the laptop's internal fan system?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: generally speaking, fans on laptop bottoms are exhaust, and those on the side or top are intake, so for most laptops having the fans point away from the laptop makes sense. In your case, having an intake on the bottom, that particular configuration may not be right for you. you can try reversing them if you like.  As for your legs, set the cooling plate on a cutting board or other flat object, to isolate you, and to ensure air flow for the laptop and cooling plate.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If there isn't a switch to reverse the fans on the stand itself are you sure it is designed to be used in your lap?

Comment: @Frank Thomas - this is wrong. Generally laptops intake is at bottom, where fan is located, which is then pushed through radiator to cool said radiator and is expelled to the side or rear of laptop. Doing it other way around would heat up other components located at bottom, instead of cooling them by air movement being sucked in by fan. As for the OP's question - yes, the fans should blow upward to cool whole bottom of laptop. Are you sure you assembled it correctly? Also: power source for those fan is USB or external? Or as Ramhound says - direction switch somewhere?

Comment: @AcePL Thanks, i thought i was going mad. No this has just come assembled, i think i will take it apart and reverse the wires then. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lavolta-Folding-Laptop-Table-Cooling/dp/B007CYBS8U/ref=pd_sim_computers_5?ie=UTF8&refRID=0T91XNA8NY9ZJJQ106WY  This is it.

Comment: *"i think i will take it apart and reverse the wires then."* -- Reversing the wires will probably cause the motor to burn out.  Also the fan blades are typically designed for rotation in only one direction.  You would want to flip the fan instead.

Comment: not to worry, they had used some crazy solder that wouldn't melt. at risking breaking the thing i gave up.. is being shipped back... if anyone has any good recommendations for a decent laptop stand you can sit with i am all ears